# Python interpreters uses up to 130% of my CPU. How is that possible?

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, load

I am currently doing some **I/O intensive load-testing** using python. All my program does is to send HTTP requests as fast as possible to my target server.

To manage this, I use **up to 20 *threads*** as I'm essentially bound to I/O and remote server limitations.

According to 'top', *CPython* uses a **peak of 130% CPU** on my dual core computer.

How is that possible ? I thought the GIL prevented this ? Or is it the way Linux 'counts' the resources consumed by each applications ?

Comment: I don't know about python, but I've certainly frequently seen the linux System Monitor reporting CPU usage of > 100%, all the way up to 180%. No idea why however.

Comment: The GIL is released on I/O calls.

Comment: I know the total 'available percentage' is 100*'Core count'. So that > 100% implies that your application runs on multiple cores. But I did not knew that the GIL was released on I/O tasks. Still, I did not know HTTP lib was multithreaded.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

100 percent in top refer to a single core.  On a dual-core machine, you have up to 200 per cent available.

A single single-threaded process can only make use of a single core, so it is limited to 100 percent.  Since your process has several threads, nothing is stopping it from making use of both cores.

The GIL only prevents pure-Python code from being executed concurrently.  Many library calls (including most I/O stuff) release the GIL, so no problem here as well.  Contrary to much of the FUD on the internet, the GIL rarely reduces real-world performance, and if it does, there are usually better solutions to the problem than using threads.

Comment: You're mixing up processors and cores!

Comment: Isn't that a very odd way of defining the CPU usage percentage? Any idea how this works with hyperthreading? My computer has 4 hyperthreaded cores, but I never see a reported usage percentage above ~180%.

Comment: With the differences in AMD/Intel Cores/Processors, superscalar, hyperthreading, Linux threads/processes, Windows threads/processes and scheduling. I challenge anyone to keep track of exactly 'how concurrent will my code be?'

Answer (score 1):

That is possible in situations when used C-extension library call releases GIL and does some further processing in the background.

Answer (score 0):

If you find this irritating, set your preferences (specifically, the preferences of your System Monitor or equivalent tool) to enable "Solaris Mode," which calculates CPU% as a proportion of total processing power, not the proportion of a single core's processing power.

Comment: It's not. I was wondering how python could use more than one core at a time but this was because I misunderstood the role of the GIL.