# Why does Python launch many processes while using threading

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi4

I wrote a Python program that uses `threading.Thread` classes. Around 25 threads are launched. It is running on a Raspberry Pi 4 (4 cores).

I was thinking that only 1 Python process would be launched when using threads (because of the GIL). It looks like 35 processes are launched.

`top` shows that python3 uses 140% CPU. (only 1 process is showing up)

`htop` shows many python3 processes. They also sum up to around 140%.

`pstree -p` shows the following (only the python part):

```
       ├─python3(28401)─┬─{python3}(28402)
       │                ├─{python3}(28403)
       │                ├─{python3}(28404)
       │                ├─{python3}(28405)
       │                ├─{python3}(28406)
       │                ├─{python3}(28407)
       │                ├─{python3}(28408)
       │                ├─{python3}(28409)
       │                ├─{python3}(28410)
       │                ├─{python3}(28412)
       │                ├─{python3}(28413)
       │                ├─{python3}(28414)
       │                ├─{python3}(28415)
       │                ├─{python3}(28416)
       │                ├─{python3}(28417)
       │                ├─{python3}(28418)
       │                ├─{python3}(28419)
       │                ├─{python3}(28421)
       │                ├─{python3}(28422)
       │                ├─{python3}(28423)
       │                ├─{python3}(28424)
       │                ├─{python3}(28425)
       │                ├─{python3}(28426)
       │                ├─{python3}(28427)
       │                ├─{python3}(28428)
       │                ├─{python3}(28429)
       │                ├─{python3}(28430)
       │                ├─{python3}(28432)
       │                ├─{python3}(28433)
       │                ├─{python3}(28434)
       │                ├─{python3}(28435)
       │                ├─{python3}(28437)
       │                ├─{python3}(28438)
       │                ├─{python3}(28444)
       │                └─{python3}(28445)
```

My question is how to explain this? Are really many processes running in parallel meaning that it would be possible to use up to 300-400% CPU? Or is it some I/O bound artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads in Linux look like processes to some tools. It's because of the way threads evolved *from* processes over time.  Basically they created "threads," by giving processes the ability to share the same virtual address space, same file handles, etc. In some sense, different "threads" within the same "process" actually *are* distinct processes with distinct process IDs.

Try `pstree --hide-threads` if you don't want to see the threads.

Comment: Thanks ! only 1 python process is displayed with --hide-threads.

I guess the python process uses more than 100% as I do much I/O stuff (mostly serial port): https://stackoverflow.com/a/11615490/1497984